# Unable to open corrupted xlsx file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

Below is the error while I try to open the file:

Excel cannot open the file '1.xlsx' because the file format or the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

I also followed the last answer of this question : [Excel cannot open an xlsx file](https://superuser.com/questions/414149/excel-cannot-open-an-xlsx-file)  but the result gave me the below details all over the file which is unreadable in English.

```
.ÞÂ@_
UÆ
kÆ[G”­uÇ˜”p‰Új•‰5_¨![3þµ·ûò;¥Ë¼«¥@~Â'IžAèÙšÒœ·³÷((kM^btô`$#ôG}/-–Ö@m¸9„g…€£,üemÂq)?š¬)”SþN`§Z8¾XwŠCíR¢_’hÒæ8¤9n%ZÔ¤øêSš¯lˆ§§;SûÀïuhnCºÙfðÈnhzïp}¢e
;?ÞvP$Ýq
ÙýðüuÁ¯´¥‹
```

Comment: Might the file be compressed? Or _uncompressed_, `,xlsx` is a zipped XML format? Password protected? Perhaps some "intelligent user" changed its name (and as in its infinite wisdom Microsoft only looks at extensions, things predictably go south from there)? Perhaps try [Libre Office](http://libreoffice.org)? Look for forensic tools, perhaps those can help rescuing something... And last, but not least, **copy the file to somewhere safe, and only experiment with copies**.

Answer (score 1):

As @vonbrand mentioned, **`.xlsx`** files are zipped. If you view the **`.xlsx`** file with a hex/binary editor/viewer, you should see something like this:

```
50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00 21 93 e5 40 09 cf  PK..............  
ae b5 23 9b e7 08 8a 77 21 0b 0d 00 00 00 66 62  ..............fi  
6c 65 6e 61 6d 65 31 2e 65 78 74                 lename1.ext
```

The first 2 characters **`PK`** indicate it is a **`.zip`** file, and the first file in the **`.zip`** file is named starting at the end of the second line (**`filename1.ext`** in this example). Between the **`PK`** and the **`filename1.ext`** will be various printable and non-printable characters that may be different for each **`.zip`** file.

If the file does not look similar, then it is probably not a **`.zip`** file, or it is a seriously  corrupt **`.zip`** file.

If you find something different in your file, edit your question to add the details of what you find.

Comment: Actually I was so stupid, that I SHIFT+DELETE the file not knowing what's in the file. After a couple of days, when I was finding the user details, I felt so helpless & stupid, cos I myself deleted the file ! And worst thing is, this is a dell vostro 1015 laptop. Please suggest, what to do, I can upload the file somewhere, if anybody wants to check it. Please ask.

Comment: So, you shift-deleted the file and then a couple days later you recovered the file and found it to be corrupted ... correct? What did you use to recover the deleted file?